# ¿Cuál es la finalidad de la medalla "Disciplinado"?

Tags: soporte, medallas

He visto que existe la medalla de bronce "[Disciplinado](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges/37/disciplined)", la cual se da cuando se elimina una publicacion propia con una reputacion de 3 puntos o más.

¿Por qué existe esta medalla, qué sentido tiene que alguien borre una publicación que ha sido bien recibida por la comunidad?

Necesito ejemplos de por qué alguien querría borrar este tipo de publicaciones.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

| Usuario | Comentario |
| --- | --- |
| Persona 0 | ¿La tierra es plana o redonda? |
| Persona 1 | ¡La tierra es plana! |
| Persona 2 | Llevas razón, +1 |
| Persona 3 | Gran verdad, +1 |
| Persona 4 | Me he emocionado al leer tus palabras, +1 |
| Persona 5 | ¿Pero sois todos idiotas? La tierra es redonda. Aquí mis fuentes: https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tierra_esf%C3%A9rica |
| Persona 1 | Pues es verdad, voy a borrar mi respuesta. |
| StackOverflow | Answer deleted |
| StackOverflow | Disciplined badge awarded |

Comment: Pues si vaya, brillante ejemplo, gracias, duda aclarada

Comment: Estoy por borrar esta respuesta para que me den la medalla...

Comment: Jaja, este comentario está mejor que tu respuesta, @ordago

Comment: Esa medalla se llama peer pressure en inglés, y expresa mejor su espíritu. Cuando los que consideras tus pares sacuden la cabeza o se dan palmetazos en la frente de pronto importa más mantener el nivel que cosechar unos votos

Comment: Al final, ¿la tierra es redonda o plana?

Comment: @RevolucionforMonica claramente es plana. ¿Qué es la tierra? Que yo sepa es un planeta, no una redondeta. El propio nombre lo indica. Jaque mate, científicos.